# Cross error uploading file from AngularJS to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, cors

i have a problem uploading files from angularjs client to NodeJS server.

The error its:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:801/bill/send-by-email. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The other $http request works fine, but this one not, this is my client code:

```
define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    var UploadService = function (API_URL, $http) {
        var uploadFile = function (file, uploadUrl) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file',file);
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: API_URL+uploadUrl,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                data: {
                    file: file
                },
                transformRequest: fd
            });

        };
        return {
            uploadFile: uploadFile
        };
    };
    return UploadService;
});
```

And this is the server code, and the cross code:

```
//Normal express definition
app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '500mb',keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: "uploads" }));
    app.use(express.json({limit: '100mb'}));
    app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '100mb'}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.all('*', require('./middleware/logger')(log));
    app.all('*', require('./middleware/cors')(log));
```

The cors file its:

```
var env = require('../env');

module.exports = function(log) {
    "use strict";

    var host = env.host;
    log.warn('Configuring Access-Control-Allow-Origin to ' + host);
    return function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", host);
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        next();
    };
};
```

And my env file:

```
var envs = {
    'development' : {
        'host' : 'http://localhost:8000',
        'sleep': true,
        'name': 'development',
        'ssl': false
    },
    'test' : {
        'host' : 'edited',
        'sleep': false,
        'name': 'test',
        'ssl': false
    },
    'production' : {
        'host' : 'edited',
        'sleep': false,
        'name': 'production',
        'ssl': true
    }
};

var node_env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
```

Anyone knows whats the problem?

Comment: Different port = different origin.

Comment: Im not doing something different like the other request, the port its same..

Comment: Well the application on `http://localhost:8000` is trying to load content from `http://localhost:801`. The port isn't the same.

Comment: This is because the port on 8000 it the angularj client and the port 801 its for nodejs server.

Comment: Therefore it's a different domain. Give the client access to the server with your CORS settings.

Comment: I set the env file with the diferent envs, one of them its localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow your client [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) access, since it's on a different domain. As your ports are different, the browser and server will recognise these as independent domains with no relation to each other.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:8000');
```

Comment: I set the env file with the diferent envs, one of them its localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

Im using like this and it works

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
            response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
            response.setHeader('X-SERVED-BY', 'Site Name');
```

try put *

Comment: I set the env file with the diferent envs, one of them its localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

Error it's the request, it have not the correct `content-type` and returns me this error. The `cors` was ok.

I edited by this:

```
define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    var UploadService = function (API_URL, $http) {
        var uploadFile = function (file, uploadUrl) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            return $http.post(API_URL + uploadUrl,fd,{
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            });

        };
        return {
            uploadFile: uploadFile
        };
    };
    return UploadService;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Enable CORS on your Node.js

Here is an URL hot to do it for several configurations
http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I did it, i describe how in the question.

Comment: You didn't even checked my URL, compare the setups since yours is clearly not working, isn't it?